VBA Macro to send indivdual sheets so separate email
I have written the macro however it is getting stuck on an "if" element (highlighted below) where data shows in a specific cell? Which then isnt allowing me to process run the rest of the macro.
Any help on why this wont work?
Sub Mail_Every_Worksheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
# If sh.Range("L9").Value Like " " Then***

            sh.Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

            TempFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & sh.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With wb
                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .to = sh.Range("L9").Value
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Name
                    .Body = "Please see attached updated P&L Report. Thanks"
                                       
                    .Attachments.Add wb.FullName
                    'You can add other files also like this
                    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                    .Send   'or use .Display
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0

                .Close savechanges:=False
            End With
            
            Set OutMail = Nothing

            Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

        End If
    Next sh

    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub


Please describe exactly what happens (error message?). "Getting stuck on" is too vague.

Line (IF sh.Range("L9"). Value Like "?@?.?*" Then) is where the debug is happening. Error message is Run-time error '13' Type mismatch?

What's the value in that cell when it stops?

Its an email address

Unable to reproduce. Maybe you have a hidden worksheet you're not considering. What does Debug.Print sh.Name, VarType(sh.Range("L9").Value) return to the Immediate Window?

If I had to guess, on one of your sheets, the cell L9 contains an error. To perform a Like, vba is looking for a string to compare against.
If L9 should only every contain e-mail addresses, you could force and cell errors to strings with something like this:
If sh.Range("L9").Text Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

Alternatively, you can prevent vba from testing the value as a string by not performing the test if it encounters an error:
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not IsError(sh.Range("L9")) Then
        If sh.Range("L9").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            sh.Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

            '.....
        End If
    End If
Next


Thank you, the change from value to text has resolved the issue
